# Recursive deletion of trie in c

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, struct, trie

I've been trying to delete a trie recursively. The typedef of the trie is as follows:

```
typedef struct _trie{

bool word;
struct _trie *link[27];
}
trie;
```

The recursive code for deletion is as follows, it takes the root of the trie as the input the first time it's called

```
void destroy(trie **node){

if(node == NULL){

    fprintf(stderr, "Could not destroy as NULL trie\n");
    return;
}

for(int i = 0;i < 27;i++){

    if((*node)->link[i] != NULL){

        destroy(&((*node)->link[i]));
    }
}

free(node);
}
```

Each time I run it, I'm getting an invalid pointer at the free(). Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Presumably you meant to `free(*node)`

Comment: What is the reason you pass `node` as a pointer to a pointer? And what happens if `*node == NULL`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if *node == null then the trie passed will be a completely empty, devoid even of a root node.

Comment: @rici thanks man!! That tweak works perfectly!!

Comment: I'm more interested in that you don't actually check for `*node` being a null pointer before dereferencing it. And you still haven'e explained the reason for using pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used a pointer to a pointer so that at no point I lose the pointer to the root and only pass a pointer to that pointer for usage. Now that might not be a very sensible approach and I'd love to know how to better it.
And thanks for pointing it out about the bug with the checking of the `*node`